# Google sheets script - chart legend text labels

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

How do you set the text label for legends in a chart via scripts in google sheets? I've looked around and all I have found are these `setOption` properties `series` and `legend` but they seem to only set the corresponding settings in chart editor (GUI). The only way I know to change the legend text is by double clicking on it in the chart.

This is the chart I tried to insert

```
var chart = sheet1.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .addRange(sheet2.getRange('A1:D12'))
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .build();

  sheet1.insertChart(chart);
```

These are the options I've tried different settings for with no luck:

```
    .setOption('series', 
      {
        position: 'right',
        textStyle: {color: 'orange', fontSize: 16}
      })
    .setOption('series', 
      {
        0: {dataLabel: 'value'},
        1: {dataLabel: 'value'},
        2: {datalabel: 'value'}
      })
    .setOption('legend', 
      {
        position: 'top', 
        textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 16}
      })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the 1st row of the range as the header row, when you create a chart using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about using `setNumHeaders` in Class EmbeddedTableChartBuilder? When your script is modified it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var chart = sheet1.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .addRange(sheet2.getRange('A1:D12'))
  .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
  .setNumHeaders(1) // <--- Added
  .build();

sheet1.insertChart(chart);
```

- By adding `setNumHeaders(1)` as above modification, "Use row 1 as headers" is checked.

#### Reference:

- [setNumHeaders(headers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-table-chart-builder#setnumheadersheaders)

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly! I changed the question a bit, s I propose that you remove the `setOption` for more minimalistic question-answer.

Comment: @dekuShrub Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I understood your proposal and I agree with you. From your updated question, I updated my answer. Thank you for your support.