# How do I add labels to a line chart legend using EmbeddedLineChartBuilder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I'm trying to make a simple line chart in a Google spreadsheet, but can't figure out how to add labels to the legend or center the title. I'm using the EmbeddedLineChartBuilder, and the only documentation I can find about adding labels to legends uses the Google visualization line chart documentation. Is there a way to do this using the EmbeddedLineChartBuilder. I do not have much experience writing scripts, and am new to JS, so please forgive my ignorance.

Here's the relevant block of code:

```js
  var table = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Quality Card Reader');
  var lastcolumn = table.getLastColumn();
  var lastrow = table.getLastRow();
  var dataEnd = table.getRange(lastrow,lastcolumn).getA1Notation();
  var data = table.getRange('A3:' + dataEnd);
  var lineChartBuilder = table.newChart().asLineChart();
  var chart1 = lineChartBuilder
    .addRange(data)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .setOption('title', 'Quality Card Progress')
    .setPosition(9,1,0,0)
    .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.RIGHT)
    .build();

  table.insertChart(chart1);
```

Here's a link to the chart that's generated:

[chart1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEZyP.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I thought that in your question, this thread might be the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67035702

Comment: That worked beautifully thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to change the values that appear in the horizontal axis? The dates on the chart don't match the dates in the data. Also, is there a way to center the title?